# Are there any drawbacks in using rename function to move files, rather than using read/write functions?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix

In linux I am trying to implement a mini shell of my own along with some basic commands as functionalities. I am planning to implement the move operation. To implement move operation, two alternatives come to my mind.

Alternative 1: use the `open(), read() and write()` functions, to open any file as a file descriptor, read the bytes and transfer the same to others.

Alternative 2: use the inbuilt `rename()` function to implement the move functionality.

I am aware that with rename, I can't overwrite existing files with `rename()` funciton. But apart from that, are there any fundamental difference in using the both alternatives?

More specifically, are there any drawbacks in using alternative 2, that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Nishant - I am trying to implement a minishell, and language of my choice for the same is C. Also the question is posted here because, through the explanations available I couldn't get answers that has to do with the portability of the code and specifically regarding why this assumption (alternative 2) can backfire

Comment: Alternative 1 allows for a "fail-safe".  In case some step fails to create the new file, the original still exists.  A failed `rename()` does not necessarily provide that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing a move by copying the contents loses all the filesystem-specific metadata (alternate streams, extended attributes, resource fork, etc.) that the file used to have. As such, copying the contents alone is insufficient for performing a move operation.

Comment: Most importantly, on normal implementations `rename` avoids needlessly reading the file from disk, and just manipulates directory data if source and target are on the same filesystem. This is quite important in a "mini shell", where the user expects to be able to move efficiently even large files.

Comment: OP, This answer does not address the post's tittle question "... any drawbacks in using rename function...".  It does well explain an advantage though.

Comment: @chux  - I agree. But the answer properly addresses my question.

Answer (score 2):

When you "move" data on the same partition, you do not need extra filespace for the rename function. Also the rename function on the same partition will be very fast, so you won't lose data written to the logfile during the move.